# Benchmarking django template engine against jinja2

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

In a Django project, I'm using Django's inbuilt template system. There's decent daily traffic, and I've been focused on reducing the server response time to improve user experience and curtail load on the server.

I haven't done much to improve page load times however. Here's the current snapshot:

[image]

Needless to say, there's lots of headroom to cover to optimize DOM processing (yellow) and page rendering (blue). Among the various optimizations I'm considering, one is replacing Django's inbuilt template system with Jinja2.

*But will that help?*

In my own research, I've read that Jinja2 templates render [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318999/why-isnt-this-jinja2-template-rendering-faster-than-djangos) than Django's inbuilt ones.

Being somewhat new to this, I need to know the best way to benchmark template rendering and DOM processing across Django's stock template system versus jinja2. For example, I've got django debug toolbar - will that help? What other tools can I use? Can a simple illustrative example be provided? Thanks!